# import file with Kivy/Buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to import file with buildozer but I can't know how

what I'm doing : in main.py there is

```
import xmpp
```

And it's should import this from file named : xmpp

it's working 100% but when I'm trying to make it an android app it isn't working

What should I do?

Comment: what do you mean with `isnt working`? please be more specific

Comment: @Borja I mean when I'm run my app on Linux (Ubuntu) it's work fine but when I'm make it an android app with buildozer not working any more when I'm open it's close immediately

Comment: @Borja who can I import file with buildozer ??

Comment: You have your own file named xmpp.py? Or this would import from some module? If the latter, did you include the module in the build?

Comment: if it's your own file(xmpp.py) then make another empty file( __ init __.py) in the same folder.